# Пробелы в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Решал задачку, условие которой построить "башню" с заданным к-л этажей. Вот так выглядит мой результат при nFloors = 5. Благодаря `blankSpace += "_";` звездочки упорядочены с центра.

```js
____*____
___***___
__*****__
_*******_
*********
```

Но в оригинале, результат должен быть без нижних подчёркиваний, то бишь, с пробелами. Но моя проблема в том, что если я ставлю `blankSpace += " ";`, то моя башня выглядит вот так:

```js
*
***
*****
*******
*********
```

Как это исправить? Вот, собственно, и мой код:

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
    let myString = "";
    for (let i = 1; i <= nFloors; i++) {
        let q = i * 2 - 1;
        let blankSpaceQuanity = nFloors - i;
        let blankSpace = "";
        for (let k = 0; k < blankSpaceQuanity; k++) {
            blankSpace += "_";
        }
        myString += blankSpace;
        for (let j = 1; j <= q; j++) {
            
            myString += "*";
            
        }
        myString += blankSpace;
        myString += "<br>";
        
    }
    return myString; 
}
document.write(towerBuilder(5));
```

Comment: на парочку `&nbsp;` поменяйте. вообще, чтобы все было ровно неплохо бы использовать моноширинный шрифт. а выводить можно не только в документ, но и в консоль. там пробелы сжиматься не будут.

Comment: В html разметке несколько пробелов сводятся к одному. А &nbsp; нет